# SwiftUI - This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness

Tags: swiftui

I'm facing with this warning when I click button to share a link, in particular below there is part of my code:

```
            HStack {
                Text(rssModel.feed.pubDate ?? Date.now, style: .date)
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                      isShare = true    // present activity
                }) {
                    Text("Condividi")
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
                .background(SharingViewController(isPresenting: $isShare) {
                    let url = URL(string: rssModel.feed.link!)
                    let av = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url!], applicationActivities: nil)
                    
                    // For iPad
                    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
                       av.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = UIView()
                    }

                   av.completionWithItemsHandler = { _, _, _, _ in
                          isShare = false // required for re-open !!!
                      }
                      return av
                  })
            }
            .font(.subheadline)
            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
```

What I'm doing in a wrong way?
I'm using XCode 14.2

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-let-users-share-content-using-the-system-share-sheet

Comment: @loremipsum thanks. But what if you are using iOS 15? this work only for iOS 16

Comment: I would recommend creating a proper solution with `UIViewControllerRepresentable` not sure where you are getting the message but that `sourceView` that isn't attached to anything is likely an issue. There are plentyy of samples on SO

Comment: @loremipsum This issue is also occurring with iOS 16's 'ShareLink', perhaps it is a bug in SwiftUI?

Comment: Possible, if you look at SO this is I believe the 3rd question with this same message today, all different frameworks but the same message. Maybe an update was pushed. It could be a "bug" or something that is being caught now that wasn't being caught before and it needs to be addressed. I have not seen it personally.